# ST_3DClosestPoint returning multiple points

Tags: postgresql, postgis

**Data**

I have 2 tables 
 - 3D point geometries (obs.geom), n=10 
 - a single 3D point (target.geom), n=1

**Problem - part 1**

When I run the following code it lists all 10 of the obs geoms rather than just the closest point to the target.geom. Can anyone give me some pointers?

```
SELECT ST_3DClosestPoint(target.geom, obs.geom)
FROM target, obs
```

**Part 2**

I then want to add in the Distance3D

```
SELECT ST_3DDistance(ST_3DClosestPoint(target.geom, obs.geom) as dist_closest, obs.geom) as distance
FROM target, obs
where dist_closest > 1.5
```

Comment: I think I have the logic backwards: ST_3DClosestPoint—Returns the 3-dimensional point on g1 that is closest to g2. I want to return g2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We cannot use knn operator(it works only with 2D) so we have to work around a bit.
For a single point in the target table it will be like this.

```
select * , st_distance(o.geom, t.geom), st_3ddistance(o.geom, t.geom)
  from obs o, target t
 order by st_3ddistance(o.geom, t.geom) limit 1
```

But it will not work if you want results for many targets at once. If you want find closest points for many targets then we have to use lateral join

```
select t2.*, a.*
  from target t2,
  lateral (select o.*
             from obs o, target t
            where t2.id=t.id
            order by st_3ddistance(o.geom, t.geom) limit 1) a
```

If you want more then one closest point just increase the limit.